# GWT regex results differ from same regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, gwt

I need a regex to test possible name of some person. It should contain Latin letters, Cyrillic letters, whitespace characters, and `_` sign.

In Java I have written the following regex, and looks like that's what i need:

```
String regex = "([\\w&&\\D]|[\\u0410-\\u044F]|[\\s])+"
```

In GWT this works not as intended: it accepts `#$%^`... etc signs. I have to write the first group as `[a-zA-Z_]` to get what I want: letters and `_` sign.

Moreover, before my modification, there was an old regex, which looked like

```
String regex = "([\\w&&\\D]+|[\\u0410-\\u044F]+|[\\s]+)";
```

Basing on my Java experience it should accept only words combined from Latin letters and `_` sign, or words combined only of Cyrillic letters or words from whitespace. But in fact in GWT it accepts all words, and even `&*(`... etc signs.

So the questions are:

1) Why is `[\\w&&\\D]` not equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_]` in GWT?

2) Why does `[...]+|[...]+|[...]+` in GWT behave like `([...]|[...]|[...])+` in Java?

Answer (score 2):

GWT generates JS, so the reason could be the regexp differences between JS and Java.

Comment: Yep, that's what it says here: [RegExp (Google Web Toolkit Javadoc)](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html).

Comment: Regular expressions and numeric types are the two main semantic pitfalls of GWT compiled code (it's good to learn this very early when starting out with GWT). There are virtually no other "language/JavaSE level" surprises in GWT, so don't be scared. For more info see http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html#differences

Comment: Thanks, Petteri, but is there some list with the differences or some explanation of the logic of these differences?